# Accessing the next object in managedObjectContext from my detailView

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a simple application that uses Core Data / ManageObjectContext. It works very similar to Apple's sample app. The fetchedResultsController grabs the objects and builds out a table view. When I click it sends the Object at that index to the detail view. Simple.

What I want to do is access the *next* Object from my current detail view so that I need not return to the table view to move through to the next detail view.

I've seen some similar questions but the answers suggest creating a mutable array which seems to defeat the purpose of core data and managed objects.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to consider renaming your question to make it more specific to `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSFetchedResultsController` caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
/* Returns the fetched object at a given indexPath.
*/
- (id)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

*Note:*

Creating a mutable array does not necessarily defeat Core Data nor `NSManagedObjectContext`, but it definitely would defeat the caching mechanism provided by `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I'm doing that in the tableViewController but are you suggesting I can use that from within the detailView? Do I need to set up a delegate first?

Comment: Yes. You can pass the `NSFetchedResultsController` to a subview, assuming you are not re-fetching anything, and that the cache won't go stale.

Comment: Awesome. I simply passed it to the detail controller and worked like a charm. Thank!!!!

Comment: checked! (can't +1 - not enough reps :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is to present the same data in a bit different way, so you can use same data source based on `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can easily get index of passed object so you'll be able to navigate between next/prev objects.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a property that refers to the master view controller on the detail view controller, or make the master view controller a delegate of the detail and make it follow a protocol with a suitable method.

Either way, the master view controller will receive a message from the detail view controller and when an action you specify takes place, you could just set the `detailItem` again on the detail view controller to the next item in your model.

This is assuming you maintain a reference to the index of the current detail item, and a reference to your detail view controller.